# How can I trace ethernet cables?

Tags: ethernet, cable

Is there some kind of device or technique for tracing ethernet cables?

I have a house that has thousands of yards of bundled ethernet cables. Some are cut and just hanging off of walls. There are dozens of jacks everywhere.

How can I find out what is connected to what?

Comment: I feel like this and your other question you just posted are too similar, and one is likely to be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks!  And it looks like there's a new model for a few bucks more that handles network cables and household wiring:  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08C8LL75R?th=1

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to trace ethernet cables.

- If the cable is plugged into smart switch on the other end, it is possible to directly ask the switch what port you are plugged into.  Devices like a fluke network analyzer will do this, and give you the port number, the switch IP address, and the switch's hostname.  Similar results can be obtained with linux (apt install lldpd; lldpcli show neighbors)
- If the cable is plugged into smart switch on one end that you can log into, and a device you can ping on the other end and you know its ethernet address, you can ping the device, and then ask the switch what port that etherent address is on.
- If the cable is plugged into a working device on one end and if you can physically access the switch on the other end and see its port status lights, and don't mind a bit of network disruption, you can make note of which ports on the switch are active, unplug the cable, and then see which port became inactive.  (Or do the reverse -- plug the device into one end and then try the loose cables on the other end and see which one the switch finds a device on.)
- If one end is not plugged into any device, but the other end is plugged into a switch and you can see its port status lights and you have a network diagnostic tool like a fluke, you can tell it to "blink" the switch port.  This works on even dumb switches, probably by repeatedly connecting and disconnecting the port at a steady rate.
- If neither end is plugged into anything, you can plug a tone generator into one end and use a tone proximity detector probe to determine which cable in a bundle has the tone on it.   These devices are relatively cheap.  If your cable is unterminated, some tone generators come with alligator clips so you could clip it directly onto stripped ends of different pairs in the cable.
- If you have a cheap network cable tester with a remote return plug, you can plug that into one end and then test potential far ends until you find the one that has the remote on it.